# Is it possible to migrate iPhone to blocked iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have an old iPhone with broken glass and some other issues.
My company sometimes has iPhones left by previous employees. Those bound to apple id and no one knows login and password to it. They say it is impossible to unlock it. I wonder if it possible to take blocked one and swap some hardware with my phone so that all the data from my iPhone would migrate to "blocked" one and it will be unblocked?

Comment: It would be considerably easier to get Apple to unlock them for you.

Comment: the question is about reusing hardware (:

Comment: Activation Lock works right to the core of an iOS device. About the only parts you could swap would be the screen & battery. If you accidentally disturb the TouchID button it will disable & never work again. Many repair operations can only be done by Apple themselves… but as they are also the only people who can unlock the device, what's wrong with taking it to them to get the whole stack of ex-employee phones unlocked? All you need is proof of ownership. Then… invest in a proper corporate MDM solution so you don't lose control of another one next time someone leaves the company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not practically possible to exchange or reuse hardware in that manner to avoid the Activation Lock. It might be possible for some very skilled, well-equipped techs at Apple - but for the rest of us - no.

Your company can however contact Apple and get the locked phones unlocked as they should have receipts, etc. on their books to prove ownership.